# Can vibrations of quite an appreciable amplitude affect the clock signal of a crystal oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I'm very curious to know as I was told that these crystals are electro-mechanical transducers. So theoretically any excess mechanical vibration should result in an error, right?

Comment: even the most ruggized SC-cut crystals with 100g 10ms shock can shift the holder and resonant frequency. Can you specify shock level or describe it? I have designed units to 0.0001 ppm max to withstand telemetry rocket shock and vibration levels.. What's your result?

Answer (score 8):

[Yes](http://www.ieee-uffc.org/frequency_control/teaching/filler_paper.html), [they can](http://www.wenzel.com/documents/vibration.html). It's probably less of a problem in normal circumstances than aging or temperature drift, but can still occur. If you can sacrifice some ppm, then [silicon oscillators](http://www.silabs.com/products/clocksoscillators/SiliconXOs/Pages/default.aspx) can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Crystals operate on the fact that when you put voltage on them they resonate. The inverse effect also occurs where the signal they produce can be changed by them vibrating. However, I have yet to see an application where this has been significant (since usually you have plenty headroom and the effect is very small). Only in certain environments it becomes significant (lots of vibration, machinery, etc).

This effect isn't relegated to crystals. In fact, cables for example can exhibit the triboelectric effect when cables are moved and the insulation is moving on top of the copper generating charges. This tends to affect very sensitive measurements.